# How do I open files from the command line in Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, textwrangler

I'm following a video tutorial where the author (who uses textmate) can open files by using "mate". for example `mate .git/config` will open this config file

I'm using textwrangler however so I don't have that option. I did try `edit .README` once when i tried to open the README file of an application, but it opened a blank README file in textwrangler instead of the file with the text in it

so any idea how I can open this .git/config file (or any other file) using textwrangler?

I'm using Mac snow leopard

Answer (score 3):

You can add this function to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`:

```
wrang() { open "$@" -a TextWrangler; }
```

Otherwise, you can open it by directly typing:

```
open /path/to/file -a TextWrangler
```

Comment: I did the following without success:  wrang() { open "git/config" -a TextWrangler; }

Answer (score 3):

If you put

```
open .git/config
```

it will be open in your default text editor for those kind of files.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the command line tools. Go to TextWrangler menu and select `Install Command Line Tools`. you will need to enter your root or admin password.